# Example code to call analyze75write from Octave?

Tags: matlab, octave

Does anyone have any example code that shows how to call `analyze75write()` from Octave?  Specifically how to create the header it expects?

I'm trying to write 32-bit floating-point images (containing positive AND negative values) from Octave into a format that can be read by ImageJ/FIJI.
To avoid all the hassles of automatic 0..1 rescaling that would come if I use `imwrite()` to write to a TIFF file, I'd like to export to
the Analyze 7.5 format.

Octave's image package offers the `analyze75write` function that would seem to be the way to do this.  But it expects two arguments - the image data as well as a header.  I can't seem to find any example Octave code that shows me how to create the header.  Can somebody provide some or point me to a link that shows how?

Here is how I'm expecting the code to work:

```
% Generate an image containing values from -5 to 5
[x, y] = meshgrid(linspace(-4*pi, 4*pi, n));
sine2 = sin(x) .* 5;

% Write it out
header = ??? THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP

analyze75write("foo.img", sine2, header)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'll recommend you take a look at the source. The function `analyze75info` only reads the header so you can get a very good idea of all that can go in there. But going through `analyze75write` it would seem that you really only need a small part of those fields (use `type fooname` to have the function source displayed on your pager or you can [browse the repository online](http://hg.code.sf.net/p/octave/image/file/default/inst)).

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I didn't realize those functions were written in Octave and I could see them via `type`.  I think I'm on the right track now and will post an example once I've got it licked.